# I can't setText() in another class in android

Tags: android, class, settext

I have a `TextView` with the id `android:id="@+id/yazi"`, and I have a button that has build in `android:OnClick="gonderB"`

and I can complie this code:

```
package com.seri.bir;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     Bilmez b;
     TextView t;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        b = new Bilmez();
        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yazi);
    }
    public void gonderB (View v,TextView t,Bilmez b){
        String s = " ..."+this;
        b.yaziYaz(v,s,t);
    }    
}

class Bilmez {
    public void yaziYaz(View v,String s,TextView t){
        t.setText(s);
    }
}
```

However I have an error.
Can I `setText` in another class?

Comment: You shouldn't.  You should call a method in the other class to get the value to set in the text, then set it in your activity.

Comment: i click button and unexpected error,main intent shut down,how can i send info and write a Textview in another class?

Comment: you are redeclaring Bilmez b in your onCreate. the global b remains null.

Comment: just change Bilmez b = new Bilmez(); to b = new Bilmez(); (remove Bilmez) in your onCreate

Comment: @TamirScherzer i changed Bilmez,remove Bilmez() in onCreate but still,it will complie but closed program after clicked button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite onClick of the activity. Avoid the using of the android:OnClick="gonderB" line in the xml file. I think it is better to implement the onClickListener and attach it to View Objects within your code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Bilmez b;
TextView t;
Button bt;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    b = new Bilmez();
    t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yazi);
    Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    bt.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View clickedView) {
    switch (clickedView.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn:
        String s = "...." + this;
        b.changeText(t,s);
        break;
    }}  //end of main class    }
```

In the changeText method you change the text of the TextView. This method can if be placed in another class if you like that.

```
class Bilmez {
            public void changeText(TextView t, String s){
                    t.setText(s);
            }
}
```

Comment: public void gonderB (View v,TextView t,Bilmez b){
        String s = " ..."+this;
        switch (v.getId()) {
          case R.id.yazi:
        b.yaziYaz(v,s,t);
        break;
        default:
        break;
            }
          }
but still didnt work

Comment: Ah you also need to implement the onClickListener and attach it to the button, I will update my code

Comment: @natrollus You can edit your question at any time with the edit link right below it. This is the preferred method of updating your question, espeically when there are changes to the code you are compiling and running.

Comment: its too usefull great answer @JanKoester

Comment: Nice class Blimez explanation on this sample - simple, working and easy to understand. +1

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you are experiencing is a need to run the function on the UI thread?

```
public void yaziYaz(View v,final String s,final TextView t) {
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         t.setText(s);
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: i put this code in my Bilmez() class but didnt work @AC Arcana

Answer (score 0):

i think you should do that:

```
public void gonderB (new View v,TextView t,Bilmez b){
    String s = " ..."+this;
    b.yaziYaz(v,s,t);
}
```

Comment: you also need to to define like that:
`b = new Bilmez();`
and not like that:
`Bilmez b = new Bilmez();`

Comment: can i remove Bilmez b; first?